# In SQLite (or Postgres), can you have a table with a variable number of row elements?

Tags: sqlite, postgresql

I am creating an activity table with many types of activities.  Let's
say activities of type "jogging" will have elements a, b, and c  while
activities of "football" will have elements a, d, and e.  Can I create a
table in which the row elements for each column depend on that column's
type?  I have considered creating one table for each activity type or
creating a single table with rows for every activity's options, but
there will be many activity types so it seems like a waste to use so
many tables or leave so many rows blank.

Comment: I think your table design is the problem here. Think about what you are trying to model in each case and then see what common elements they all have and then turn those common parts into an abstract class. As an idea have one table for activities, and then a 2nd table for properties that has a many to one relationship with the first table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot create such a table, it is not in the nature of databases to allow for "varargs". That is the reason we have relations in databases to model this type of stuff.

For an evil quickhack you could store the variable number of arguments in one column in a specific format and parse this again. Something like "a:foo|e:bar|f:qux". Don't do this, it will get out of hand in about 1 day.

I second James' proposal: redesign your tables. It should then look something like this.

```
Table: Activities
id|activity
0|jogging
1|football
2|...

Table: ElementsOfActivities
id|activity_id|element
0|0|a
1|0|b
2|0|c
3|1|a
4|1|d
5|1|e
```

Look up "normalization" (for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: The consensus I'm getting is that the tables need to be redesigned.  I would rather not use a module to get around this if I am designing the database with bad form (plus, I am making this with Rails so I don't want to deal with potential incompatibilities with Rails and hstore).  I will use your idea, Yashima, it requires one extra table but doesn't complicate development.

Answer (score 1):

I assume in the subject you mean *column* instead of *row* because the whole concept of a table is around the fact that is *has* a variable number of rows. The same goes for your statement "leave so many rows blank" - again I assume you are talking about **columns**.

What you are describing is essentially an (anti) pattern called "entity attribute value". Search for this and you'll find a lot of hits describing how to do it and why not to do it.

In Postgres things are somewhat easier. It has a contrib module called "hstore" which is essentially what you are looking for. "Multiple columns inside a single column".

The biggest drawback with the hstore module is that you lose type safety. You can only put character data into a hstore column. So you cannot say "the attribute *price" is numeric, the attribute *name* is a character value".

If you can live with that restriction, hstore is probably what you are looking for in Postgres

Answer (score 0):

It's complicated. The short answer is, "No." 
You should ask yourself what you're trying to report on, and try to figure out a different schema for tracking your data.

If you really want to implement a variable-column-count table, you can do something close.

Define the activity types, and the elements you'll track on each one, and a junction table to resolve the many-to-many relationship. These tables will be mostly static. Then you have an Activity table and an ActivityAttribute table.

Create an Activity table, and then have an Activity Type, Activity Element, Activity Type-Elements and Activity Attribute tables.

Types would be "jogging", "football".

Elements would be "a", "b", "c", "d"...

Type-Elements would have rows that look like "jogging:a", "jogging:b", "jogging:c", "football:a", "football:d"

Attributes would have the actual data: "18236:a:'0:10:24'", "18237:d:'356 yards'"

Comment: This is essentially what the hstore module provides with the added benefit that it can be indexed .

Answer (score 0):

Tables aren't a limited resource (in reasonable practice) so don't obsess about creating lots of them "wasting" them. Similarly in most modern databases, null columns don't take up space (in postgresql, beyond a minimal "null bitmask" overhead) so they aren't a particularly precious resource either.

It probably makes sense to have a table to represent distinct sets of attributes that can be defined together (this is essentially one of the general rules of database normalisation). If you want to deal with "activities" in a generic way, you may want to have common attributes in a shared table, rather like a base class in OOP... or you may not.

For example you could have:

```
jogging(activity_id int, a type, b type, c type)
football(activity_id int, a type, d type, e type)
```

and then create a view to combine these together when desired:

```
create view activity as
select 'jogging', activity_id, a, b, c, null as d, null as e from jogging
union all
select 'football', activity_id, a, null, null, d, e from football
```

Alternatively you could have:

```
activity(activity_id int, a type)
jogging(activity_id int, b type, c type)
football(activity_id int, d type, e type)
```

and then:

```
create view activity as
select case when jogging.activity_id is not null then 'jogging'
            when football.activity_id is not null then 'football'
       end,
       activity_id, a, b, c, d, e
from activity
     left join jogging using (activity_id)
     left join football using (activity_id)
```

These models are mostly equivalent, the main difference being that the second one provides a clear path to a distinct activity_id identifier, which is one reason many people would prefer it, especially when using an ORM to persist the data (although you can do it the first way too by sharing a sequence).

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, and it's good to know excess tables and null columns are not too costly.